# Triggers and multi-column Primary Keys

Tags: mysql, triggers, primary-key

I have a books table and a music table.  Both of these tables have a Product_ID as their primary key.  I also have a products table that has a Product_ID column and a type column (0 for books, 1 for music) where the Product_Id and Type columns are the primary key for the table.  In phpMyAdmin, these 2 columns are underlined and SHOW COLUMNS for the table shows Type and Product_Id marked as primary keys.

The problem I'm having is with my trigger.  There are 2 triggers, with a couple of differences to handle the different tables.  The music trigger for example executes this statement:

```
 INSERT INTO products 
 SET 
      Type=1, 
      Product_Id=NEW.Product_ID,
      Title=NEW.Album, 
      Price=0
```

The books trigger is the same, except type=0 and NEW.Album is replaced with NEW.Title.  When I'm running an INSERT query now though, after some data has been inserted and deleted, I'm getting a duplicate primary key error.  The problem is that the MySQL database is only reading the Product_ID column as a primary key, so when its trying to insert a duplicate there, it spits out this error even though it the value in the Type column is different.  I'm stumped here.

The products table

```
Product_Id  int(11) - PK
Title   int(11)
Price   double
Type    int(11) - PK
NewBool tinyint(1)
```

The music Table

```
Product_ID  int(11) - PK
Artist  varchar(32)
Album   varchar(32)
Genre   varchar(32)
Year    int(11)
Length  double
Rating  double
NumRatings  int(11)
Studio  varchar(64)
```

The books table

```
Product_ID  int(11)  - PK
ISBN    bigint(20)
Title   text
Author  text
Year    int(11)
Genre   text
Pages   int(11)
Publisher   text
Edition int(11)
Rating  double
NumRatings  int(11)
```

Comment: Please post your tables definitions. I dont think MySQL will ignore a primary key definition otherwise there would be a lot more complaints like this.

Comment: I added the tables in question in my post.  Checking from the MySQL Console and in phpMyAdmin, the products table shows that Type and Product_ID are the primary key for that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have forgot a trigger that deletes rows in Products. If you ever update the data in Books or Music you also need a trigger that makes the corresponding change in Products.

Here is your problem now
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be9c93/1

Here is how I've fixed it
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ff27/2

Comment: That's not a bad idea and I'll probably try to do that sooner rather than later, but can that cause the problem I'm having now?  The table I see only has one value with that primary key and no match on both Product_ID and Type

Comment: Check out the fiddle I just made